# Usage of "you any good?"

Tags: phrase-usage, subject-verb-agreement

> You any good?

I found this line in the movie *Cable Guy*. I really like it and have never heard it anywhere before.

In what situations could I use this line?

Comment: This is conversational deletion, the ellipsis of predictable function words at the left edge of an utterance in casual speech. The full form is *Are you any good?*

Answer (score 1):

Usually it can be used after an activity is described.

> We are about to play some football.  You any good?

or

> I heard you got that new game.  You any good?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone's ability to do something is being questioned. I would take it to mean:

> Are you good at [doing] X? (For example, using a gun.)